# React native app can't connect to websocket server running on localhost

Tags: react-native, websocket, localhost

Given the below code, the socket initialized with `wss://echo.websocket.org/` calls onopen. The one pointing at my local-running server, does not.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props

    // this doesn't work (doesn't call onopen)
    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/websocket");

    // this works (calls onopen)
    this.socket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org/");
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.warn('Mounting..')

    this.socket.onopen = () => {
        console.warn('onopen');
        this.socket.send('Ping')
        this.setState({ connected: true }, this.subscribe)
    };

    this.socket.onerror = (error) => console.log('Error: %o', error);
    this.socket.onmessage = (message) => console.warn('Server: ' + message.data);
}
```

I can reach and connect to both services with `wscat`

```
project master % wscat -c wss://echo.websocket.org/
> connected (press CTRL+C to quit)

project master % wscat -c ws://localhost:3000/websocket/
> connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
```

What am I missing here?

(and Obviously, I'm not calling `this.socket = new WebSocket()` 2x in my code, it's just for comparison.)

Comment: I figured it out... I'm a dummy. localhost != my phone's localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a late night and I'm a dummy. `localhost` needs to the address of your server running on your network.